# AutoMapper ForMember method breaks the functionality of mapping

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, dto

I want to use AutoMapper in my .Net 6 APIs to convert the entity model `User` to DTO model `UserDTO`.
The `User` model class is:

```
public class User : BaseEntity
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;
  public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;
  public string Avatar { get; set; } = null!;
  public string Email { get; set; } = null!;
  public ICollection<Book>? FavoriteBooks { get; set; }
}
```

And the `UserDTO` is a record as follows:

```
public record UserDTO(Guid Id, string FullName, string Avatar, string Email);
```

I have added the required package `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection` v.12.0.0,
and the configuration steps are given below:
1- Create `MappingProfile` that inherits from the `Profile` class

```
public class MappingProfiles : Profile
{
  public MappingProfiles()
  {
    CreateMap<User, UserDTO>()
      .ForMember(
          dest => dest.FullName,
          opt => opt.MapFrom(src => string.Join(" ", src.FirstName, src.LastName))
      );
  }
}
```

2- Register the service in `Program.cs` file:

```
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));
```

3- Use the mapper as an injected service inside `Service` project:

```
public IEnumerable<UserDTO> GetAllUsers(bool trackChanges)
{
   var users = _repository.User.GetAllUsers(trackChanges);
   return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<UserDTO>>(users);
}
```

When I call the `GetAllUsers` method in postman, I get the following error:

> Error mapping types.
> Mapping types:
> List -> IEnumerable

After a few days of struggling and searching, I realized that the `.ForMember()` method breaks the functionality of the profile class. In other words, if I change the `UserDTO` record:

```
public record UserDTO(Guid Id, string FirsName, string Avatar, string Email);
```

the `FullName` filed changed to `FirstName` to have compatibility with the `User` model. Also change the `MappingProfile` class:

```
public class MappingProfiles : Profile
{
  public MappingProfiles()
  {
    CreateMap<User, UserDTO>();
  }
}
```

the `GetAllUsers` method works as expected. So to conclude, if I add the `.ForMember()` method to the constructor of the `MappingProfile` class as in documentation, it breaks the functionality of the `CreatMap` method.

How should I use the `.ForMember()` method to map the `User` model to the corresponding DTO? Is this method obsolete? Is there any replacement for this method?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I want to know how should I map my entity to the corresponding DTO using `.ForMember()` method or any replacement for that.

Comment: Either change the return type of the GetAllUsers as List<UserDTO> or change the return type of the repository's GetAllUsers as IEnumerable<UserDTO> as your _mapper.Map is trying to convert the List<User> to IEnumberable<UserDTO>. One mapping User -> UserDTO is configured in profile but the AutoMapper is also looking for the List -> IEnumerable also.

Comment: It is not related to converting IEnumerable to List or vice versa, it works correctly without `.ForMember()`, by the way, I have tried that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 2 solutions:

**Solution 1:**
I created a method to get the full name of the user. The method name should be prefixed with get:

> The naming convention can cover simpler examples where the source object has a property, method, or method with a “Get” as a prefix with the same name as the property of a destination object.

so I have modified the `User` model class and added the following method:

```
public class User : BaseEntity
{
    ... // User model properties
    public string GetFullName() => $"{this.FirstName} {this.LastName}";
}
```

and removed the .ForMemeber()` method from the profile class:

```
public MappingProfiles()
{
    CreateMap<User, UserDTO>();
}
```

**Solution 2:**
It seems that `.ForMember()` is obsolete, I have found an alternative for that, `.ForCtorParam()`:

```
public MappingProfiles()
{
    CreateMap<User, UserDTO>()
      .ForCtorParam(
          "FullName",
          opt => opt.MapFrom(src => string.Join(" ", src.FirstName, src.LastName))
      );
}
```

In these ways, I have converted my `User` model class to `UserDTO`.